# Purely CSS Dropdown isn't working in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I just built http://www.utahaddictioncenters.com/ and noticed the dropdowns in the main navigation aren't showing at all in IE. When you move down to the bottom of the nav item, you can see a tiny lighter shade appear on hover, but the rest of the menu doesn't show up. I've tried doing set heights, changing z-index, and a few other things, but nothing is working.

Comment: Yes, sadly IE is one of greatest annoyances for web developers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a stacking issue to me. **There are issues when you have absolutely positioned elements and relatively positioned elements in IE** so it's just a matter of figuring it all out. I would highly recommend moving to a javascript-based dropdown or a jQuery dropdown. Doing this might help you out since javascript can behave differently. It also makes figuring out these issues easier! I see that you're using wordpress, you can download a plugin to do this for you! Not a definitive answer, but at least it's a start!